# Web Browser no Sound USB G930

Tags: sound, alsa

I am using the `Logitech G930 Gaming Headset` on `Mageai` with the `KDE` desktop environment. Within Chromium I am unable to hear any sounds; the volume button indicates noise when I manually adjust the sound and I can hear that without a problem.

This is some sort of browser issue as I have tested `Firefox`,`Konqueror` and `Links GUI` all resulting in the same outcome of no sound. I have performed the following:

1. Made the G930 the master channel on the Volume Control
2. Gone into `Volume Control` and ensured that the output device for my headset is not muted (I can hear the tests perfect)
3. Ran `alsamixer` and ensured no channels were muted.

The next step would be to confirm `Flash Player` was installed and operating. I have installed the latest version and ensured all works with a reboot. Upon reboot I attempted to run `alsamixer` again and received the following error message:

```
    Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse):
    Permission denied
    ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect:
    Connection refused
    Cannot open mixer: Connection refused
```

I am not entirely sure how to correct this issue, but will do some investigating. Are there any other avenues I can follow up to try and understand why Google Chrome/Chromium is not playing audio?

**Update 1** I have attempted to use standard headphones (and not USB connected) and they work without an issue. I am unsure if there are any special setups needed for a USB connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed the proprietary drivers (unable to relocate where I downloaded these from) and then edited `alsamixer`.

Using the USB direct to the PC and not to the Wireless Hub allowed me to select the headset USB receiver as the sound device and I was able to play sound from the headpiece.